# Loop to generate random words/datetime for 32 columns, for 1 million records to be inserted into MySQL is incredibly slow

Tags: mysql

I have some PHP code that I've modified, it basically has 3 functions one that generates random letters, the other 2 generate a random date or time. I then use a "For" loop to call each function to build out an array of values to be inserted into a MySql "main" table. However, the process seems very slow. On a side note, I have a trigger on this "main" table that will concatenate all the columns into one column and inserts it into another table. Any help on how to speed this process up would be greatly appreciated.

I'm wanting to populate 1 million records with somewhat unique data in each column to test some search query performances. Below is the code:

```
    function genWord($numberOfWords) {
        $words = [];
        for ($s = 0; $s<$numberOfWords; $s++){
            //for ($i=0; $i<$numberOfWords; $i++){
            $worLen = rand(3,10);
            $word = "";
            for($j=0; $j<$worLen; $j++){
                // Ascii table uppercase letters
                $chVal1 = rand(65,90);
                // Ascii table lowercase letters
                $chVal2 = rand(97,122);

                if ($j == 0) {
                    $picker = rand(0,1);
                    if($picker ===0 ) $ch = chr($chVal1);
                    else $ch = chr($chVal2);
                }else $ch = chr($chVal2);
                $word = $word.$ch;
            }
            $words[] = $word;
            //}
            $sentence = implode(" ", $words);
        }
        return $sentence;
    }

    function genDate() {
        //Generate Random Date format yyyy/mm/dd
        $randomDate = '';
        $year = rand(1950,2018);
        $month = rand(1, 12);
        $thirtyOneDayMonths = array ('1', '3', '5', '7', '8', '10', '12');
        $thirtyDayMonths = array ('4', '6', '9', '11');

        // 31 day months
        if (in_array($month, $thirtyOneDayMonths)) $day = rand(1,31);
        // 30 day months
        else if (in_array($month, $thirtyDayMonths)) $day = rand(1,30);
        // month equal to Feb
        else $day = rand(1,28);

        $month = str_pad($month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $day = str_pad($day, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $randomDate = $year."-".$month."-".$day;
        return $randomDate;
    }

    function genTime() {
        // Generate Random Time hh/mm/ss
        $randomTime = '';
        $hour = rand(1,23);
        $min = rand(1,59);
        $sec = rand(1,59);
        $hour = str_pad($hour, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $min = str_pad($min, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $sec = str_pad($sec, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $randomTime = $hour.":".$min.":".$sec;
        return $randomTime;
    }

for($n=0; $n < 10000; $n++) { 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table1( 
    col1, 
    col2, 
    col3, 
    col4, 
    col5, 
    col6, 
    col7, 
    col8, 
    col9, 
    col10, 
    col11, 
    col12, 
    col13, 
    col14, 
    col15, 
    col16, 
    col17, 
    col18, 
    col19, 
    col20, 
    col21, 
    col22, 
    col23, 
    col24, 
    col25, 
    col26, 
    col27, 
    col28, 
    col29, 
    col30, 
    col31, 
    col32)
    VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";


    // Generate values for table1
    $insertValue = array();
    for($c = 0; $c < 32; $c++) {
        if ($c <=1) {
            $fileDate = genDate()." ".genTime();
            $insertValue[] = $fileDate;
        }
        else if ($c == 8) $insertValue[] = rand(1, 14);
        else if ($c == 10) $insertValue[] = 0;
        else if ($c == 14) $insertValue[] = rand(1, 20);
        else if ($c == 19) {
            $fileDate = genDate()." ".genTime();
            $insertValue[] = $fileDate;
        }
        else if ($c == 21) {
            $fileDate = genDate()." ".genTime();
            $insertValue[] = $fileDate;
        }
        else if ($c == 23) {
            $fileDate = genDate()." ".genTime();
            $insertValue[] = $fileDate;
        }
        else $insertValue[]= genWord(1);
    }

    //print_r($insertValue);


    if ($pdo) {
        // Table1
        $stmt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($insertValue);
}
```

Comment: You could significantly improve the date generation performance by generating a random timestamp between 1950 and 2018, instead of each separate date element. E.g. `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', rand(-631155600, 1546297199))`;

Comment: @fubar thanks I'll give this a try!

Comment: Also look to do bulk inserts, rather than inserting each individual row. And if you don't need the data in the first table, but only in the second, just insert it into the second table immediately. It'll save 1M insert queries.

Comment: @fubar I'll have to look up bulk inserts then thanks for the tip again!

Comment: One other thought, disable keys on insert. `ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE KEYS;` and reenable when finished `ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE KEYS;`